# what are classes, enumerations, Interfaces, Attributes?

Tags: class, unity-game-engine

I am developing a unity game. I just still don't understand details about classes, enumerations, Interfaces and Attributes? How do each of these work? What is the difference between my classes (that I have to create) and unity scripting api classes (that already exist)?

Comment: This question is way too vague. I suggest you dive deep into understanding Unity through books, youtube videos or other resources first, then ask specific doubts if you have any.

Comment: These are C# concepts. Learn a bit of C# first, then go back to Unity.

Comment: can you give me Detail document? or please explain for me detail? how classes work? WHY I HAVE TO CREATE MY OWN CLASSES?

Comment: How about you make use of documentation and yt tutorials and then when you have a specific question, come here?

Comment: There's a lot of information out there regarding C# and Object Oriented Programming. Use it to learn the basics, this isn't the right place to ask for a tutorial on OOP and C#.

Comment: Look for introduction to programming materials. Try beginner section here: https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/s/scripting but you probably need some primer about C# and coding first

Comment: where is right place to ask?

Answer (score 0):

Classes are a blueprint that define behaviour. If you want your game to have any kind of behaviour it will be defined in a class. You would for example create a "Player.cs" class which would define how the player behaves.

I could go through each one but the question is too broad and it would be more beneficial if you looked for some material about the basics of c#, object oriented programming and Unity.

Unity has video tutorials on the fundamentals of these topics here => [Link](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/s/scripting).

I hope you find them useful.